# Computing $\lim_{a\to\infty}\operatorname{erf}(a+z)$

Tags: limits, analysis, special-functions

Let $z\in\overline{\mathbb C}$. I want to compute
$$L \equiv \lim_{\mathbb{R} \ni a \to \infty}\operatorname{erf}(a+z).$$

Can I use the fact that $z + \infty = \tilde{\infty}$ where $\tilde{\infty}$ is complex infinity to conclude that$$L=\displaystyle\lim_{\mathbb{R} \ni a\to\infty}\operatorname{erf}a=1?$$

Comment: @parsiad $a$ is an element of extended reals, so it's a real limit. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Your claim is true, but since $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ does not have a unique limit as $|z|\rightarrow\infty$, you cannot make the argument you suggest. Maybe try to split up $\operatorname{erf}(a + z)$ into its real and imaginary parts and show that they go to 1 and 0, respectively as $a \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @parsiad But how can I split $\operatorname{erf}$ into its imaginary and real parts?

Comment: Note also that the case of $z \in \overline{\mathbb C} \setminus \mathbb C$ is not well-defined, for the same reason I give above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can massage equations (5) to (7) of [1] to show that for any real numbers $x$ and $y$
$$
\operatorname{erf}(x+iy) = \operatorname{erf}(x) + f(x,y)
$$
where $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x,y) = 0$ for each $y$.
It follows that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \operatorname{erf}(x+iy) = 1$, as desired.

[1] Salzer, H. E. "[Formulas for calculating the error function of a complex variable](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2002163)." *Mathematical Tables and Other Aids to Computation* 5.34 (1951): 67-70.

---

For posterity, I include the relevant part of [1] below.
Note that the author defines $\Phi(Z) \equiv \int_0^Z e^{-u^2} du$ (i.e., the error function integral *without* the usual scalar multiplier).

[image]